# Calculate a bearing in a data.table of points (lead) / calculate between rows of the same table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, apply

I have trouble to understand how to apply lead on a data.table
I would like to calculate bearing between the current point and the next point.
So basically calculate bearing between current and the next row in the data.table.

Here what i have tried:

I have the route data.table

```
library(geosphere)
library(data.table)
route<-structure(list(counter = 1:6, lon = c(11.829711, 11.8336202, 
11.8333238, 11.8341994, 11.8336198, 11.8337213), lat = c(48.1091400999115, 
48.1153102999101, 48.1269571999072, 48.1273386999071, 48.1297995999066, 
48.1309630999063)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55b3b7da26f0>)
```

next I create the "lead" data.table for (next) rows

```
  lead_route_dt<-route[, data.table::shift(.SD, 1, NA, "lead", TRUE), ]
```

And try to apply `bearingRhumb` on both data.tables:

```
 apply(data.frame(route$lon,route$lat), 1, FUN = function(x) bearingRhumb(x,cbind(lead_route_dt$lon_lead_1,lead_route_dt$lat_lead_1)))
```

but sadly as result i get an error:

```
 Error in if (sum(keep) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What packages are you using? The function bearingRhumb is not part of base R. What is the definition of bearing?

Comment: Sorry library is called geosphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to `bearingRhumb` not handling `NA`:

```
bearingRhumb(c(NA,NA),c(11,42))
#Error in if (sum(keep) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

You need to exclude rows containing `NA` from calculation:

```
route[,`:=`(next_lon = shift(lon,1,type='lead'),next_lat = shift(lat,1,type='lead'))]
route[!(is.na(next_lon)),bearing:=bearingRhumb(cbind(lon,lat),cbind(next_lon,next_lat))]
route

   counter      lon      lat next_lon next_lat    bearing
1:       1 11.82971 48.10914 11.83362 48.11531  22.928957
2:       2 11.83362 48.11531 11.83332 48.12696 359.026720
3:       3 11.83332 48.12696 11.83420 48.12734  56.865278
4:       4 11.83420 48.12734 11.83362 48.12980 351.066053
5:       5 11.83362 48.12980 11.83372 48.13096   3.332292
6:       6 11.83372 48.13096       NA       NA         NA
```

Comment: Thank you waldi! you helped me again as often before. Just to be clear. point 1 has no bearing but point 2 is 22.928957 or is 22.928957 for point 1?

Comment: @Andreas, see my update so that first point has a bearing